# d3 tricking voronoi tesselation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geometry

I have a set of points and lines connecting some of the points. I want to draw perpendicular bisectors through these lines and find the connecting points of these bisectors to form an image like a voronoi diagram.

However, since all the points are not being considered to create the diagram, I decided not to use `d3.geom.voronoi()`.

Instead, I wrote code to draw the perpendicular bisectors myself. However, I am having problem finding where the bisectors themselves intersect so that they can stop being extended to form polygons.

Here is what it currently looks like...

[image: The red lines denote the bisectors]

The black lines denotes connection between points and the red lines the perpendicular bisectors to them.

Since, my requirements are so close to a voronoi diagram, I was wondering whether I could somehow use `d3.geom.voronoi()` to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find the the two triangles on both sides of any edge in your diagram, you can try the following pseudo code. I have tried it on a full delaunay triangulation and it works.

```
For each _valid_ edge:
  vertLeft  <- circumCenter(faceLeft)
  vertRight <- circumCenter(faceRight)

  collect Edge(from: vertLeft, to: vertRight)
```

This will give you all the edges you need as segments, i.e. with a start and end point.

One case to watch out for is when the edge is part of the convex-hull of the vertices, in this case there will only be one *finite* triangle on one side. You can get the direction vector for such a line just like you are doing right now --perpendicular vector to the original edge.

If you have access to one of the geometric data structures commonly used for representing planar tessellations (Half-edge, winged-edge, quad-edge, etc. --I am not sure what d3 uses.), this should be fairly simple to implement (in case of quad-edge, this is trivial, since you already have all the information you need).